# Current open session in Oracle

Tags: oracle, oracle12c

Is there any way to get the number of current open session for a particular user without having access to v$session or any dba tables?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the number of sessions by the following OS commands

```
netstat -an | grep (database port) | wc -l
```

Comment: Yeah but this we will need server access, Which won't be possible in production so not an option for us.

Answer (score 2):

No, there's not, since this information may not be allowed to all users of the database.

If you want to query v$session view and have any security concerns (or your DBA does), you can simply create a view on top of the standart one, filter data from it as required, and grant access on it to a user.